# VBScript to `drop` and `create` new table in microsoft access

Tags: vbscript

I have VBScript to `drop` and `create` new table in microsoft access. 
**My vb script is :**

```
Set dbeng = CreateObject("DAO.DBEngine.120")
strMdbFile = "amw\db_amw.accdb"
Set db = dbeng.OpenDatabase(strMdbFile)
strSql1 = "DROP TABLE amw"
StrSql2 = "SELECT * INTO amw FROM MPN_V WHERE (((Format([tgl_bayar],'yyyy')) Between Format(Now(),'yyyy')-2 And Format(Now(),'yyyy')))"
strSql3 = "DROP TABLE UPDATE"
strSql4 = "SELECT * INTO update FROM UPDATE6 WHERE id="1""

db.Execute(strSql1)
db.Execute(strSql2)
db.Execute(strSql3)
db.Execute(strSql4)
```

when the script runs the line `db.Execute(strSql1)` and `db.Execute(strSql2)`, no error Happen. but, when the script runs the line `db.Execute(strSql3)` and `db.Execute(strSql4)`, error Happen : `Expected end of statement, code 800A0401, source Microsoft VBScript compilation error`. Please correct my Script? thank you verymuch

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the number of quotes on the last SQL statement.

```
strSql4 = "SELECT * INTO [update] FROM UPDATE6 WHERE id="1""
```

If "id" is an integer, use the following:

```
strSql4 = "SELECT * INTO [update] FROM UPDATE6 WHERE id=1"
```

If "id" is a string, use the following:

```
strSql4 = "SELECT * INTO [update] FROM UPDATE6 WHERE id=""1"""
```

Doubling the quotes are necessary when working with a string within a string.

Comment: with your advice, i have use `strSql4 = "SELECT * INTO update FROM UPDATE6 WHERE id=""1"""` displays an error message `The Select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing or the punctuation is incorrect"`. then I have changed into `strSql4 = "SELECT * INTO [update] FROM UPDATE6 WHERE id=""1"""`, script runs successfull